# Can't Split STL using an N-gon made from Plane (Boolean Intersect/Difference)

Tags: 3d-printing, boolean-modifier, stl

[image]

So I have this STL I want to split up and since I want to slice it along existing geometry. I added a plane and many loop cuts, then fill the top and bottom to get the image you see.

However, every time I try either Boolean Intersect or Difference, the N-gon is the only thing left and the STL disappears. What am I doing wrong?